# Signed curvature of circle involute

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'm supposed to prove that the only plane curve (up to a direct isometry) whose signed curvature is $\kappa_{s}(s)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}$ ($s$ is the unit-speed parametrization) is the circle involute.

I'm having trouble with this because my calculations just don't add up: let's say we have a unit circle $\alpha(s)=(\cos{s},\sin{s})$, so its involute would be $\gamma(s)=(\cos{s}+s\sin{s}, \sin{s}-s\cos{s})$, if I'm not mistaken. One of many ways to find the signed curvature is as $\kappa_{s}^{\gamma}(s)=\frac{x'(s)y{''}(s)-x{''}(s)y'(s)}{\mathcal{v}^3}$, where $x$ and $y$ are the coordinates of $\gamma$. This can't possibly result in $\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}$, because of the sines and cosines. Am I going wrong somewhere, or is the formulation of the problem wrong?

Comment: I may be wrong (because it's very late for me) by I think your problem is with curvilinear abscissa: $s$ is curvilinear abscissa for the unit circle, but no longer for the curve described by $\gamma(s)$...

Comment: Oh, that's right. I need to divide everything by $\mathcal{v}^3$... I'll see if that yields any results.

Comment: I've tried dividing by $\mathcal{v}^3$, but I still get $\frac{s^2}{(1+s^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$, which means that the given signed curvature is probably the involute of a very "strange" parametrization of a circle.Is there a way to determine whether a curve is an involute based solely on its signed curvature?